# How to pass down kubernetes service endpoints IP into KAFKA advertised listener

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

I would like to configure Kafka broker in Kubernetes. The docker image I am using is `confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest`. It requires `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` environment variable which allows Kafka client to communicate with broker.

The problem is the difficulty to assign service endpoints IP to `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. If I am using `localhost` as this value, it is only working in local Kafka broker pod but it won't work for some Kafka client pods in kubernetes cluster to communicate with it. If I am using the service endpoint IP coming from `kubectl get endpoints -l app=kafka`, this is working but it is little overhead to use some audit script set this dynamic value every time.

I wonder is there a better way I can dynamically set this value in Kubernetes yaml file, so I don't need to programatically set this IP every time.

Here is the yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      hostname: broker
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: "PLAINTEXT://DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_IP:9092"
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "1"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zoo1:2181
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**  I tried to use Server name, Service host environment variable, service source IP and Pod IP. Unfortunately, I still get the error in kafka log: 

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://$KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST:9092': Unable to parse PLAINTEXT://$KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST:9092 to a broker endpoint`

If I am using `kubectl exec -it kafa-broker-ssfjks env`, those environment variables are actually set correctly in this pod. I guess it may be related to a Kafka broker configuration issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should let your clients connect through the service, so exposing the ip or dns of the service should work. By default services are exposed as variable names in the pod. If a dns plugin is configured dns can be used. More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables

Comment: Just to clarify, this solution would work for a deployment with one replica only - as specified in the question. (Kafka cluster with multiple brokers doesn't properly work behind load-balancers. Service can be used only for bootstrapping, but the advertised address has to point to the specific brokers.)

Comment: So basically you could use a StatefulSet and hardcode the members in the env variable. Or how would you update the list of listeners when another replica is started?

Comment: When you use StatefulSet, you can use headless service which will give each pod a fixed hostname / DNS record which can be used as the advertised hostname within the Kubernetes cluster. But you will need to figure out the hostname inside the image (for example using `hostname -f` in the Docker entrypoint script) - I have never used the Confluent Docker images, so I'm not sure whether that's possible with it. Although you will know the hostname for each pod upfront, you cannot use it in environment variable because there is only one template for all pods created by the StatefulSet.

Comment: I tried to use $KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST environment variable in `"PLAINTEXT://$KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST:9092"`. However, kafka throws some errors like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://$KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST:9092': Unable to parse PLAINTEXT://$KAFKA_BROKER_SERVICE_HOST:9092 to a broker endpoint`. I will edit into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the service name (kafka-broker) instead of it's IP. Kube-dns will resolve it for you. If the kafka client was placed at same namespace, you should use just "kafka-broker", if not, you must use the qualified name "kafka-broker.YOURNAMESPACE.svc"

Comment: This does not seem to work, the pod hits the following exception (though it is able to establish connection with zookeeper using kubernetes service):

INFO Socket connection established to zookeeper.default.svc.cluster.local/10.103.99.26:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
...
WARN [Controller-1-to-broker-1-send-thread]: Controller 1's connection to broker kafka-broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect within 30000 ms
at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady

Answer (score 0):

@Jakub got me on the right track, so for something like cp-kafka-connect my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
ENV CONNECT_GROUP_ID='kafkatosql'
ENV CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="kafkatosql-config"
ENV CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="kafkatosql-offsets"
ENV CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="kafkatosql-status"
ENV CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
ENV CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
ENV CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="ERROR"
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:5.4.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY start.sh .
CMD exec ./start.sh
```

and then start.sh looks like:

```
kafka_connect_host=localhost:8083

export CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(hostname -I)

/etc/confluent/docker/run &

wait_counter=0
echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect ⏳"
while true; do
  status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://$kafka_connect_host/connectors)
  if [ $status -eq 000 ]; then
    wait_counter=$((wait_counter+1))
    echo "Kafka Connect listener HTTP status: $status (waiting for 200)"
    if [ $wait_counter = 15 ]; then
      echo 'Waited too long!';
      exit 1;
    else
      echo "Retries: $wait_counter"
      sleep 3
    fi
  else
    break
  fi
done
echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connect Postgresql Sink"
curl -X PUT http://$kafka_connect_host/connectors/jdbc_sink_postgresql_00/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": 1,
  "topics": "users",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:'"$DB_URL"'",
  "auto.create": false
}'

# ... other stuff

trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait
```